# Returning callback function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tired I read all return value from callback but not any one please help me.

I have a database and I do aggregation and I want take a total value and use the return value in another function

```
function daly(x, callback) {
  tarry = [];
  sale.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      salepro: "mouse"
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: "id",
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: "$saleprice"
      }
    }
  }], function(err, rs) {
    tarry.push(rs);
    console.log(tarry);
    return callback(tarry);
  })

  console.log(tarry);
}
```

Comment: you can use `promise` or `async` module or `bluebird` library.
check this out 
https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md

Comment: You cannot use the `return` statement to return data form an async function.  You have to use a  _callback_, _Promises_ or `await`/`async`.

Comment: thanks but  help me to  make a function  return the total field from the (sale.aggregation) and make it global variable